# How can i replace hide button in this code with toggle?

Tags: jquery, hide, toggle

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ex .hide").click(function(){
    $(this).parents(".ex").hide("slow");
  });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css"> 
div.ex
{
background-color:#e5eecc;
padding:7px;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Island Trading</h3>
<div class="ex">
<button class="hide">Hide me</button>
<p>Contact: Helen Bennett<br /> 
Garden House Crowther Way<br />
London</p>
</div>

<h3>Paris spécialités</h3>
<div class="ex">
<button class="hide">Hide me</button>
<p>Contact: Marie Bertrand<br /> 
265, Boulevard Charonne<br />
Paris</p>
</div>

<h3>Paris spécialités</h3>
<div class="ex">
<button class="hide">Hide me</button>
<p>Contact: Marie Bertrand<br /> 
265, Boulevard Charonne<br />
Paris</p>
</div>

<h3>Paris spécialités</h3>
<div class="ex">
<button class="hide">Hide me</button>
<p>Contact: Marie Bertrand<br /> 
265, Boulevard Charonne<br />
Paris</p>
</div>

<h3>Paris spécialités</h3>
<div class="ex">
<button class="hide">Hide me</button>
<p>Contact: Marie Bertrand<br /> 
265, Boulevard Charonne<br />
Paris</p>
</div>

<h3>Paris spécialités</h3>
<div class="ex">
<button class="hide">Hide me</button>
<p>Contact: Marie Bertrand<br /> 
265, Boulevard Charonne<br />
Paris</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

what im trying to do is to replace hide button with toggle butto. So every time i press button i can hide or show info. How i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Because the button gets hidden at the moment, you won't be able to show again.

What about if you remove the buttons, and use a click on the header to toggle the other info?

Like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h3").click(function(){
    $(this).next("div").toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

...or you could keep the button and just toggle the `<p>` element after it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ex .hide").click(function(){
    $(this).next("p").toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to have the button outside the div it toggles in order to toggle with it.
- You need to have separate id's for you div's